# How to end() a file stream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a weird issue with a piece of sample code that I got [here](http://sunilkumarn.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/node-js-streams-and-pipes/), the central part being this:

```
server.on('request', function(request, response) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream('copy.csv');
  var fileSize = request.headers['content-length'];
  var uploadedSize = 0;

  request.on('data', function (chunk) {
    uploadedSize += chunk.length;
    uploadProgress = (uploadedSize/fileSize) * 100;
    response.write(Math.round(uploadProgress) + "%" + " uploaded\n" );
    var bufferStore = file.write(chunk);
    console.log(bufferStore);
    console.log(chunk);

    if(!bufferStore) 
    {
      request.pause();
    }
  });

  file.on('drain', function() {
    request.resume();
  });

  request.on('end', function() {
    response.write('Upload done!');
    response.end();
  });
});
```

The problem is, the file `copy.csv` does not contain anything after the process is finished.
I tried to add `file.end();` in the `request.on('end'`-callback, but it did not do the trick. However, if I add faulty code in said callback that causes an exception, the file is being written just fine (although this ofc can't be the final solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To notify the stream that there are no more chunks to be read, you can simply call `your_stream.push(null)`. You can read more about streams and `push(null)` [from the excellent substack's stream guide](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook#creating-a-readable-stream).

Answer (score 1):

Try this structure:

```
var file = fs.WriteStream('copy.csv');
    fileSize = request.headers['content-length'],
    uploadedSize = 0;

request.on('readable', function () { // Node.js 0.10 (Streams2 interface)
    var newData = this.read() || new Buffer(0); // Sometimes may come null
    file.write(newData);
    uploadedSize += newData.length;
    response.write(Math.round((uploadedSize / fileSize) * 100) + "%" + " uploaded\n" );
});

request.on('end', function () {
    response.write('Upload done!');
    response.end();
    file.end();
});
```

Comment: Does readable still do the chunk-handling? Also, where do I close the response here? I tried using the `request.on('end'` event, but when I send the response there, the `copy.csv` file is empty. If I do not close it there the transmission works well, but ofc the browser keeps awaiting a response.

Comment: @Romiox, see the updated answer, it does everything you want, the approach that I used is the recommended one for Node.JS 0.10, you are using the old API events from 0.8

Comment: I am trying to use this, but I still run into a couple of issues, usually something along the lines of an empty or not fully written `copy.csv` file. But I am still trying-- I will get back to you as soon as I can narrow the problem down.